# Replace a relay with an analog switch

Tags: ground, cmos, grounding, solid-state-relay, analog-switch

I'm trying to replace a relay with a SPDT cmos analog switch MAX4678 for switching a sine wave, The switch is powered with dual power supply +5/-5 and +5 to its V_logic pin.

This is what i got in mind:
[image]

I tried the two setups and both of the works but which one is better and has low distortion ?

Comment: Neither of those shows a complete circuit. You are missing power supply connections, voltages and ground references. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Thanx @Transistor, As said in the description V+ = VL = +5v , V- = -5v,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first diagram, as long as abs(V2) is < 5v, the switch voltage stays within the rails. Which means it will work.

In the second diagram, there is no mechanism shown to maintain the switch voltage between the rails. Depending on what you haven't shown, it may work, or it may not.

Comment: This is what i thought , So the analog signal and the switch must share a ground reference unlike when using a relay.

Comment: @HM47   No. If I saw a relay with no circuitry shown between signal and ground, I'd give exactly the same warning, it may or may not work. However, in practice, a relay has a much higher voltage range allowable between signal and control circuits, usually 1500V to cope with mains isolation, whereas your switch was 5v, a voltage that's trivially easy to exceed. You're not comparing silicon with metal, you're comparing a high voltage and a low voltage component. Use each within their specifications. In practice, the silicon has protection diodes, so limits more safely than the relay.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind Thanx.